# Unity, APK Installs but does not open on my phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

when i build my game and install the apk on my phone, i dont get any errors or warnings but when i try to open it the app immediately closes but still no errors, only error is something like this : "this app not working right now please wait for the publisher to patch it". any help would be great.

i have tried changing api version, deleting my android file in the unity and resolving, and installed the apk on a different phone, i have tried the solutions i found here but they also did not work.

Comment: If the build of your APK is debuggable, there should be a crash log in logcat. Make sure that you filter for the package name and not only the currently running process. It can happen that crashlogs dissappear once a process stopps.

Comment: unfortunately there are not any crash logs in the logcat. but this is my first time using it. maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: crashing an app can be for several reasons, for troubleshooting you should export the project to android studio and then run it, you can easily find tutorials on everywhere how to debug unity android app

Answer (score 0):

Crashing the app when opening, most of the time it is related to the initialization of some plugins.
Did you add a plugin or package recently?

Comment: Yes i indeed added a plugin. also the problem with the logcat solved when i reinstalled android studio. the problem was with the installation of google ad manager. i decided to uninstall it since it wasn't crucial for my project and the problem was gone. thanks everyone.